# Load one or more views within a CI Template loader class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Referring to the top answer on this post:

[Header and footer in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540576/header-and-footer-in-codeigniter)

How could you update this class to support multiple views if required?

e.g. sometimes loading two or more views between the header and footer templates...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What about the variables? Should each view has a different set of variables or all the views have the same variables?

Comment: They could possibly have different variables if that is what you mean, sorry if it isn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each view to have it's own vars:

```
public function template($template_names = array(), $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    $content  = $this->view('templates/header', $vars, $return);
    foreach ($template_names as $template_name -> $template_vars)
    {
        $content .= $this->view($template_name, $template_vars, $return);
    }
    $content .= $this->view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

    if ($return)
    {
        return $content;
    }
}
```

.

```
$this->load->template(array(
    'body' => $vars_for_body,
    'body2' => $vars_for_body2,
    'body3' => $vars_for_body3
), $headerfooter_vars);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - i almost had something like this :) P.S thank you to Hashem Qolami for providing a solution too. I went for Samutz in the end.

Comment: @Random You're welcome, I tried to implement a little more complex algorithm. which gives you a better functionality.

Answer (score 1):

*Well,* here is my attempt to improve the functionality of the template function:

```php
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function template($template_name = array(), $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $content  = $this->view('templates/header', $vars, $return);

        if (is_array($template_name)) {
            foreach ($template_name as $view => $viewVar) {
                // Whether the view has different variables
                if (is_array($var) && ! is_numeric($view)) {
                    // Load the view with its own variables
                    $content .= $this->view($temp, $viewVar, $return);
                } else {
                    // Load the view whith the general variables $vars
                    // viewVar would be the view name in this case
                    $content .= $this->view($viewVar, $vars, $return);
                }  
            }
        } else {
            $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
        }

        $content .= $this->view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

        if ($return)
        {
            return $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this, you could load the views in the format below:

```php
$this->load->template(array(
    'first/view' => array('name' => 'value'),
    'second/view',
    'third/view'
), $generalData);
```

Each view can have its own variables.

In this case, The **first view** is loaded by passing the `array('name' => 'value')` as its variable. And the **second/third views** are loaded with `$generalData` as the variable.

If you need go get access to `$generalData` in the first view, you could use `+` operator to merge the variables as: `array('name' => 'value') + $generalData` or vice versa.