# Avoid mentioning to load the header and footer all the time

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i avoid loading giving the load of `header` and `footer` in all the views.

I want to load in the page. but i don't want to to mention to load everytime.

Is there anyway to load it in common. So my code will be less

Here is the controller i have

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('includes/index');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }

public function blog()
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('includes/blog');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
    public function contact()
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('includes/contact');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
```

Comment: you can add it to the views rather than using it in Controller.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540576/header-and-footer-in-codeigniter