# Header and Footer can't use globally in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I have been called header and footer for all pages in view.

For this I created a new file in application/core/MY_Loader.php

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
        if ($return):
            $content = $this->view('header', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view('footer', $vars, $return);

            return $content;
        else:
            $this->view('header', $vars);
            $this->view($template_name, $vars);
            $this->view('footer', $vars);
        endif;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->template('welcome_message', $data);
```

What i have to do, to get the header and footer in all pages?

Currently my `welcome_message` view file only loaded not the header and footer.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540576/header-and-footer-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Yep. I have used the same code which they accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your method to this:

```
public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
    if ($return):
        $content = $this->load->view('header', $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->load->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->load->view('footer', $vars, $return);

        return $content;
    else:
        $this->load->view('header', $vars);
        $this->load->view($template_name, $vars);
        $this->load->view('footer', $vars);
    endif;
}
```