# My (header,footer) and js,css,image,favicon load only in index method not in other in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to code igniter and integrating bootstrap template with code igniter. i have created several pages in template already and try to integrate it with CI.

**my css and js structure like below:**

```
application
assets
         css/style.css
         js/min.js
         img/imagename.jpg
```

**My controller file as below**

```
     <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function services()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('services');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

*As per my understanding i need to create an different method for the different page so i can put it within header and footer. please let me know if i am wrong here.*

I have created one folder named as **templates** in **view** and put create `header.php` and `footer.php` and put header and footer code in particular file.

**my .htaccess file as below**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Than i creted a view named as home in **view** folder and put html code and include all js and css here like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="assets/css/reset.css" />
```

And it work perfect.

**But when i create another view as service and put `css` and `js` same as above than in my service view i cannot get data from `header.php` `footer.php` and also not load `css` or `js` or images.**

And than i used url helper like below:

```
<script src='<?php echo $this->base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
```

And it loads js files and css files but not get the proper view. and still **header** and **footer** files are not loaded in **service** view. So can i get any help from code igniter experts.

Comment: put index.php before asset

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap is it for the css and js??

Comment: But why my heder and footer not load that i did not get.

Comment: just remove all rule from .htaccess then try is it working?

Comment: i remove all the code from .htaccess but still i cannot get header and footer data.

Comment: put your folder structure here. in ci it should be views not view so check is it proper name or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Header and footer in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540576/header-and-footer-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cause error, view file load looks ok. Change this.

```
<script src='<?php echo $this->base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
```

as following and try

```
<script src='<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js');?>'></script>
```

make sure you have set your `base_url` in config.php as `http://localhost/project_name/`

If you getting still any error to load view files, post your error details here

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but my js and css file loaded with both the code as above. but the header and footer cant load with service method. that i can't understood

Comment: when i run http://localhost/cinew1/welcome/services than it shows the content which in services views. and also give effect of css and js. But i cant load content which is in my footer.php and header.php and also i dont know hot to use base_url for images so images are also not loading in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: i use wamp server

Comment: nice click on the wamp icon in your taskbar >apache>apache modules>(scrolldownand select) rewrite module restart wampp services

Comment: worked? a good tip  use the autoload file to load helper/libraries  if your gonna use it throught your application save you space and the trouble to copy paste it again and again  ....unless you know how to use __ constructs()

Comment: i already done this. but my problem is that why my images, header, footer not loading in services views.??

Comment: base_url() set? in cofig file

Comment: `$config['index_page'] = '';`    `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/real';`

Comment: my base url is $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cinew1/'; my problem now only is why templates/header.php  templates/footer.php and images not loading.

Comment: in your images you load it the same way you call your external scripts and your css files

Comment: hmm spelling mistake may be?  check folder names also  ... view names are case sensitive so if your file name starts with a capital call it with a Capital

Comment: i load images as  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?=base_url();?>assets/apple-touch-icon-57x.png" />

Comment: yea but is neater to do <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?=base_url('assets/apple-touch-icon-57x.png');?>" />

Comment: hmm spelling mistake may be? check folder names also ... view names are case sensitive so if your file name starts with a capital call it with a Capital   your view files are in template folder check the folder name is same

Comment: same thing work in index method as above i put code of my controller. you can see.

Comment: change your  htaccess rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]`  to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] `   QSA and a ? after index.php

Comment: when i hit url as http://localhost/cinew1/welcome/index than it will not load any css or images or js.

but when i load http://localhost/cinew1 it will load perfect

Comment: or just replace your htaccess with mine `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]`