# codeigniter not working without index.php in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with a codeigniter project and I am able to use codeigniter out of the box when I install it on a digital ocean ubuntu droplet. However, when I load this project I want to use, if index.php is not in the url, the project breaks and I see a 404 error: The requested URL was not found on this server.

There is a login page at domain.com/index.php/login
Even when I login, it gets redirected to domain.com/dashboard without the index.php

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is my config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://my_really_cool_domain.com';
```

Oddly enough, if I add /index.php/ to the base_url it works, but the CSS / javascript resources do not load. Not sure why I am facing this error.

Comment: if assets not loading properly then refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39738642/6309457

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply changes as below :

Try to replace `uri_protocol` in `config.php` as it,

```
//find this `index_page`
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
// replace with it
$config['index_page'] = ""


//find this `uri_protocol`
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO" 
// replace with it
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

[For more refrence](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/)

## Check default.conf

On my site, I use `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
On your site it might be `/default.conf`

You need to add this line:

```
AllowOverride all
```

This is what my conf file looks like:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/html>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Content"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                Require valid-user
                Options +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Then restart apache:  `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

Missing question mark ? after index.php in .htaccess, so

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is Correct Way

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In Linux hosting environment this is usually required.