# Extending core loader causing issues when loading view

Tags: php, codeigniter

[Template loader taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541565/970057). While trying to use `$this->load->view()` in a view file it's throwing issues about `MY_LOADER` unless the return value is specified as true.

**Extended template loader**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
        if($return) {
            $content  = $this->view('templates/header', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this->view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

            return $content;
        } else { 
            $this->view('templates/header', $vars);
            $this->view($template_name, $vars);
            $this->view('templates/footer', $vars);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Basic controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->template('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

**welcome_message**

```
<?php echo $this->load->view('account/login'); ?> // Throws error
<?php echo $this->load->view('account/login', array(), true); ?> // No error
```

If I don't define the return value as *true* it throws an error `Object of class MY_Loader could not be converted to string`

**Full stacktrace**

```
    A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class MY_Loader could not be converted to string
Filename: views/welcome_message.php
Line Number: 71
Code on line 71: <?php echo $this->load->view('account/login'); ?>

Backtrace:

File: application/views/welcome_message.php
Line: 71
Function: _error_handler

File: application/core/MY_Loader.php
Line: 17
Function: view
Code on line 17: $this->view($template_name, $vars);

File: application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 26
Function: template
Code on line 26: $this->load->template('welcome_message');

File: index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once
```

This use to work fine in CI.2, what's the cause of the issue?

Comment: When loading a view on a view not this way `<?php echo $this->load->view('account/login'); ?>` try with out echo `<?php  $this->load->view('account/login'); ?>`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 That was the fix, was driving me insane.

Comment: have put answer up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using view's like below with out echo

```
<?php $this->load->view('account/login'); ?>
```

Instead of

```
<?php echo $this->load->view('account/login'); ?>
```

Codeigniter view [guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)