# Codeigniter MY_loader is not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create a header / body / footer template in CodeIgniter similar to that described at:
[Header and footer in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540576/header-and-footer-in-codeigniter)

My code stored at \application\core\MY_loader.php:

```
<?php
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    public function load_template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        if($return):
            $content  = $this -> view('templates/header', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this -> view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $this -> view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

            return $content;

        else:
            $this -> view('templates/header', $vars);
            $this -> view($template_name, $vars);
            $this -> view('templates/footer', $vars);

        endif;
    }
}
?>
```

My controller code stored at application\controllers\managers.php:

```
class Managers extends CI_Controller {
    function login()
    {
        $this -> load -> load_template('managers/login');
    }
}
```

When I browse to BASE_URL/managers/login, I get this error:

*Call to undefined method CI_Loader::load_template()*

My interpretation of this is that the system is not extending CI_Loader with MY_Loader, but is instead disregarding MY_Loader entirely. This setup was working on my local install of the site when I was running it under XAMPP, but it stopped working after I ported the site to a web host. I don't remember changing the CI configuration (although I might have), nor do I know if this is due to a configuration issue at the new host.

I am looking for any guidance as to what might be preventing MY_loader from extending CI_loader. I haven't been able to find any similar reports; all the other issues I've found related to MY_loader assume that the override is already working.

Comment: save your file as `MY_Loader.php`.

Comment: The file is already saved with that name.

Comment: I apologize...I missed the capitalization on "Loader". You were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file has to be called "MY_Loader.php" - it is case-sensitive and NOT the same as "MY_loader.php".

Contrary to the only other answer at this time, "My_loader.php" will NOT work either, as the `subclass_prefix` is applied separately from the library name.

The simplest way to exemplify it is this:

```
$libraryName = 'loader';

$className   = ucfirst(strtolower($libraryName));
$className   = config_item('subclass_prefix').$className;

$fileName    = $className.'.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Save as MY_Loader.php this (Thanks to  other friend's suggestion that "L" is also has to be capital letter)

```
    public function load_template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        if($return):
            $content  = $CI->load->view('templates/header', $vars, $return);
            $content .= $CI->load->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
            $content .= $CI->load->view('templates/footer', $vars, $return);

            return $content;

        else:
            $CI->load->view('templates/header', $vars);
            $CI->load->view($template_name, $vars);
            $CI->load->view('templates/footer', $vars);

        endif;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope I could help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same error:
*Call to undefined method CI_Loader::load_template()*

I don't think the issue is with the load_template() code--I don't think the system is finding the MY_Loader module in the first place.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter2 ? Could you try to  add "MY_loader" to application/config/autoload.php on the libraries section

Comment: İf it didnt work again. Try to use helper (for example Login_helper.php in application/helpers folder) and load with helper with autoloader in config folder ($autoload['helper'] = array('Login');) then call function. İf you still need help İ could add these on answer

Comment: @jdiz414 check in config.php which value has $config['subclass_prefix'] it was NEW_ for me, not MY_ and correct it in file name or config