# CodeIgniter Template Parser Extends MY_Parser To Auto Load/Parse Header Footer

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, parameters, controller

My template parser looks like this (p/s the .'/'. is for readability):

```
$this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'header', $data);
$this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'register', $data);
$this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'footer', $data);
```

I don't want to declare `$this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'header', $data);` and `$this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'footer', $data);` every time in my controller's functions.

How can I extend the `MY_Parser.php` so that I could use it like this instead:

`$this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'register', $data);` will include the `register.php` between my `header.php` and `footer.php` automatically.

The benefit of doing this is to save 2 lines and if I have 20 functions, I can save 40 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a function (can be a helper, library extension or model):

```
function tpl($view, $data) {
    $this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'header', $data);
    $this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.$view, $data);
    $this->parser->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'footer', $data);
}
```

If you want you can extend `Parser` and make a `MY_Parser` in the libraries folder and do:

```
class MY_Parser extends CI_Parser {
    function tpl($view, $data) {
        $this->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'header', $data);
        $this->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.$view, $data);
        $this->parse($this->settings['theme'].'/'.'footer', $data);
    }    
}
```

Usage:

```
$this->parser->tpl($view, $data);
```

You could do this using `$this->parser->parse()` but that would require more code as you overwriting the default method and it's just as easy to introduce a new method.

**UPDATE:**

*Using the `MY_Parser` method you might have to access `$this->settings` via `$this->CI->settings` thereby referencing the CI instance in `CI_Parser` depending on where this variable is coming from.*

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Right now, I'm creating a function `$this->render('register');` in MY_Controller (which extends CI_Controller) where register is the file to include and in that `render();` function automatically includes the header and footer + data to parse. Is this better than extending the CI_Parser?

Comment: I tend to keep only setup logic and variables in my controller. I think extending parser is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create class with the name of your prefix class name in application/core folder and follow below code. $this->input->is_ajax_request() will only load view other then header and footer if request is from ajax. and in each controller you need to extend YOUR-PREFIX_Controller instead of CI_Controller

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class YOUR-PREFIX_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $header_data;
    protected $footer_data;
    protected $header_view;
    protected $footer_view;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->header_view = 'path-to-header';
        $this->footer_view = 'path-to-footer';
    }

    public function _output($output) {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            echo ($output);
        } else {
            echo $this->load->view($this->header_view, $this->header_data, true);
            echo ($output);
            echo $this->load->view($this->footer_view, $this->footer_data, true);
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I'm currently using template parser to parse `{title}` for example. Why isn't there any reference on `$this->parser->parse` and this method is using ajax? How do I call your function? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to load only view through ajax in popup this will load only view file and this will ignore header and footer file. you just need to extend this class instead of CI_Controller in each of your controller

Comment: replace YOUR-PREFIX_ with subclass_prefix which you have defined in application/config/config.php

Comment: I don't think this is actually what I was looking for but I can try to change `$this->load->view` to `$this->parser->parse` to see if the data is parseable. I get logic, now...

Comment: if this will not work please comment i will delete this answer so anyone else will not be confused

Comment: I've found a workaround. on my controller, I call a function `$this->render('register');` which extends `MY_Controller` (which extends CI_Controller) and the function goes like `public function render($filename) { $this->parser->parse('header',$data); $this->parser->parse($filename,$data); $this->parser->parse('footer',$data); }` ----- what do you think?

Comment: actually this is what i am referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540576/header-and-footer-in-codeigniter